# While Loop Still Triggering When not Supposed too

Tags: javascript, while-loop

Doing a while loop in JavaScript but it's displaying 120 when usernum < 50 but calculating when usernum is 60.

```js
var userNum = 4; // Code will be tested with values: 4, 10 and 60
/* Your solution goes here */
do {
  userNum = 2 * userNum;
  console.log(userNum);
}
while (userNum < 50);
```

CORRECT Testing displayed output with userNum = 4
Yours
8
16
32
64

CORRECT Testing displayed output with userNum = 10
Yours
20
40
80

INCORRECT Testing displayed output with userNum = 60
Yours and expected differ. See highlights below.
Yours
120
Expected
Expected no output

Comment: `while` is not the same as `do-while`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **do while** loop runs the code once, and then tests the condition, if it is false, it stops the execution. You should use **while** or **for** loop.

```
while(userNum < 50){
userNum = 2 * userNum;
console.log(userNum);
}
```

**while** -> check condition, if true run code, else stop

**for** -> check condition, if true run code (basically shorter version of while)

**do while** -> run loop, check condition, if true run again or exit;

Comment: You got it.. Nice